# AMD-Intel Hybrid Graphics : Problem

Tags: ati, graphics, intel, hybrid-graphics

My Laptop is an HP DV6 6121tx with 2 GPUs: An Integrated Intel one and an AMD HD6770M.

Now I just want to run Ubuntu on it without getting horrendous battery life and without it getting very hot after a few minutes.

My BIOS has 2 options regarding this: Fixed switching and Dynamic switching. 
In FIXED mode, in Windows, I could manually choose which GPU to run my system on.
In DYNAMIC, in Windows, I could choose which apps would run on which GPU, switching was seamless.

Now I don't mind running Linux on ANY of these modes, I don't even require my AMD GPU for anything, I just do some general coding on Linux here and there.

So here's my question. What should I do to run my system on the Integrated Intel GPU? Very importantly please also mention that whatever method you suggest is for FIXED mode or DYNAMIC mode.

(Ubuntu 12.10)

Comment: This is slightly different than the answer you've asked for but the best guide I've seen for installing the ATI drivers is [here](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29_BETA.2FEXPERIMENTAL). Since you have a hybrid system, you are probably affected by this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1068404), but see the workaround [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI#WORKAROUND). The workaround solved the fan/heat problems on my DV6 with hybrid graphics.